# The images are showing broken link for ecommerce site

Tags: php

The images are showing broken link. My images are not showing. Only a box is shown in place of it.

```
function getPro(){

if(!isset($_GET['cat'])) {
          if(!isset($_GET['brand'])) {
global $con; 

$get_pro = "select * from products order by RAND() LIMIT 0,6";

$run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro); 

while($row_pro= mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){
    $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
    $pro_cat = $row_pro['product_cat'];
    $pro_brand = $row_pro['product_brand'];
    $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
    $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
    $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];

    echo "
            <div id='single_product'>

                <h3>$pro_title</h3>

                <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='180' height='180' />

                <p><b> Price: $ $pro_price </b></p>

                <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>Details</a>

                <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id'><button style='float:right'>Add to Cart</button></a>

             </div>
    ";
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you look at the URLs that the broken images are set to, you may get a hint to what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: And your question is...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to make a conceptual mistake constructing your output string:

- `$val = "Hello World"; echo $val;` will output "Hello World"
- `$val = "Hello World"; echo "$val";` will output "$val"

Try something like this

```
echo "<div id='single_product'>
            <h3>" . $pro_title . "</h3>
            <img src='admin_area/product_images/" . $pro_image . "' width='180'
            [...]"
```

Comment: @BigBI Could you please update and post your changed code? Further, it could be very useful to view and/or post the html source output.

Comment: @BigBI Thanks! Please do also post the <img> tag from your html output source.

Comment: @BigBI Thanks again for posting your code. I am sorry for the misunderstanding we had. PHP is a server-side scripting language. In your case it outputs (or at least should output) a html source code. You just posted your PHP Code but it would be great of you (for the purpose of finding the error) to post the PHP output which is HTML. (That is the source your browser will use to display the page. Try typing view-source: followed by the URL into the address input of your browser)

Comment: @BigBI What are your filenames?

Comment: admin_area    /    index.php   /    insert_product.php

Comment: @BigBI Please excuse me if I am wrong but HTML, PHP etc. seems to be quite new to you. - Are you sure that you are actually running the script on a server with PHP installed? PHP is a server-side scripting language.